# Handling Screen Rotation on an App With Two Fragment placeholders for tablet, One For Mobile

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to develop an app which scales well for a phone, and a tablet. My initial thinking here would be that I need to create three activity xml files (one for the mobile device, and another for the tablet[in portrait], and another for the tablet [in landscape]). The one for the mobile device has a single FrameLayout, where I programatically load the login Fragment. The layout file for tablet (the portrait one), also has a single FrameLayout. The last layout file for the tablet (in landscape), has two FrameLayout's, where I load two Fragments programatically. Before loading fragments, I thought you would need to first do some calculations - to see if the current device is a mobile phone or a tablet, and then check if the tablet is in portrait or landscape. Then, after these calculations are done, you load the necessary fragment(s). All of this I have done, I am now stuck with handling screen rotation.

How do I make sure that the mobile app loads currently loaded fragments? As it stands, if I navigate further into the app (go into registration), it will load this fragment, but, when the tablet or phone is rotated, it takes me back to the first fragment that got loaded - which is the login fragment.

I thought maybe I would need to make use of the Activity's onPause and onResume methods to save and reload currently open fragments - this would be fine for mobile but I imagine it would be tricky with tablet.

So my question is, how do you handle screen rotation for an app which is made for mobile and tablet - the layout plans are different.

Here is the code in my MainActivity:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getData();
    setSocialMedia();
    mainActivityToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.MainActivityToolbar);
    toolbarTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MainActivityToolbarTextView);
    setSupportActionBar(mainActivityToolbar);
    loadLoginFragment();

}
```

Here is the code I created which checks if the device is a phone, or tablet, then checks orientation, then loads the needed fragment(s):

```
 private void loadLoginFragment(){
    deviceUtils = new DeviceUtils(this);
    isTablet = deviceUtils.isTablet();
    if (isTablet) {
        toolbarTextView.setText("Log In To Continue");
        isLandscape = deviceUtils.isLandscape();
        if (isLandscape) {
            LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            LoginInformationFragment loginInformationFragment = new LoginInformationFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction loginTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            loginTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewTabletOne, loginFragment);
            loginTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            loginTransaction.commit();

            FragmentTransaction informationTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            informationTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewTabletTwo, loginInformationFragment);
            informationTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            informationTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            LoginFragment loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewTabletLand, loginFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    } else {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewMobile, new LoginFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Any help, or tips would be great :) Thanks.

Comment: I think that you need to make Registration as activity, but not the another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Android offers a lot of support in handling different types of devices and does a lot of the work for you. If you haven't already, I suggest that you take a look at [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSizeQuali) and the associated material in Android training. Also take a look at [Handling Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). The [documentation for fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) also has some good information about embedded fragments.

Another good example is [Implementing Adaptative UI Flows](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html) which has a section on detecting and reacting to the current layout.

I have also found [this write-up](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) from Alex Lockwood to be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you handle screen rotation for an app which is made for mobile and tablet - the layout plans are different.

If I understand your cases correctly, your app will only show the fragment in portrait when it is running on mobile, while may show single pane (portrait) or dual panes (landscape) in tablet depends on the orientation. If this is the case, then you may achieve this by using the **Smallest Screen Width** and **Orientation** configuration qualifiers.

You need to create two activity_main.xml, which one with a FrameLayout and another with two FrameLayouts, and store in the main>res>layout and main>res>layout-sw820dp-land respectively:

Example activity_main.xml in main>res>layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivityContentViewOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Example activity_main.xml in main>res>layout-sw820dp-land:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainActivityContentViewOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainActivityContentViewTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your MainActivity, you load the fragments by checking whether the second FrameLayout with the MainActivityContentViewTwo id is exist (first FrameLayout with the MainActivityContentViewOne id is always exist in any of your cases):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // any of your code ...

    // load the fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewOne, new LoginFragment());
    if (findViewById(R.id.MainActivityContentViewTwo) != null)
        // app is running in tablet and landscape configuration
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.MainActivityContentViewTwo, new LoginInformationFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```